# python execute many with "on duplicate key update"?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am trying to executemany in python with on duplicate key update, with the following script:

```
# data from a previous query (returns 4 integers in each row)
rows = first_cursor.fetchall()

query="""
INSERT INTO data (a, b, c)
VALUES (%s,%s,%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a=%s
"""
second_cursor.executemany(query,rows)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 212, in executemany
  self.errorhandler(self, TypeError, msg)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 35, in defaulterrorhandler
  raise errorclass, errorvalue
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Is this even possible without creating my own loop?

Comment: this error happens when the number of items do not match what you are supposed to fill in and what actually you are passing.
>>> a = 1

>>> b = 2

>>> print "%s" % (a,b)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

>>>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a bug in MySQLdb due to the regex that MySQLdb uses to parse `INSERT` statements:

In **/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/MySQLdb/cursors.py**:

```
restr = (r"\svalues\s*"
        r"(\(((?<!\\)'[^\)]*?\)[^\)]*(?<!\\)?'"
        r"|[^\(\)]|"
        r"(?:\([^\)]*\))"
        r")+\))")

insert_values= re.compile(restr)
```

Although there have been numerous [bug reports](http://sourceforge.net/p/mysql-python/bugs/209/) about this problem that have been closed as fixed, I was able to reproduce the error in MySQLdb version 1.2.3. (Note the [latest version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/) of MySQLdb at the moment is 1.2.4b4.)

Maybe this bug is fixable, I don't really know. But I think it is just the tip of the iceberg -- it points to much more trouble lurking just a little deeper. You could have for instance an `INSERT ... SELECT` statement with nested `SELECT` statements with `WHERE` conditions and parameters sprinkled all about... Making the regex more and more complicated to handle these cases seems to me like a losing battle.

You could use [oursql](http://packages.python.org/oursql/); it does not use regex or string formating. It passes parametrized queries and arguments to the server separately.

Answer (score 8):

When you write sql like following:

```
sql = insert into A (id, last_date, count) values(%s, %s, %s) on duplicate key update last_date=%s, count=count+%s'
```

You will get the following error: `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting.`

So when you use `"ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"` in python, you need to write sql like this:

```
sql = 'insert into A (id, last_date, count) values(%s, %s, %s) on duplicate key update last_date=values(last_date),count=count+values(count)'
```

Answer (score 4):

found:

```
on duplicate key update col1=VALUES(col1), col2=VALUES(col2)
```

https://hardforum.com/threads/python-mysql-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting.1367039/

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug of mysqldb as ubuntu said, sightly change the sql then it works:

```
insert into tb_name(col1, col2) select 1,2 on duplicate key update col1=1
```