# MySQLdb returns not all arguments converted with "on duplicate key update"

Tags: python, mysql-python

With MySQLdb package in python, I want to insert records with checking some unique keys. The method I used is executemany. The arguments are sql sentence and a tuple. But when I executed it, it raised an error which said "not all argument converted".
The codes are as following:

```
dData = [[u'Daniel', u'00-50-56-C0-00-12', u'Daniel']]
sql = "INSERT INTO app_network_white_black_list (biz_id, shop_id, type, mac_phone, remarks, create_time) " \
      "VALUES ({bsid}, {shop_id}, {type}, %s, %s, NOW()) " \
      "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE type={type}, remarks=%s, create_time=NOW()".format(bsid=bsid, shop_id=shop_id, type=dType)
cur.executemany(sql, tuple(dData))
```

Someone said this is a bug. But they didn't give me a path to jump over it. Please provide a method if this is a bug.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python executemany with "on duplicate key update"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825232/python-executemany-with-on-duplicate-key-update)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

### What's going wrong

After checking the link in [your comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337065/mysqldb-returns-not-all-arguments-converted-with-on-duplicate-key-update#comment41410860_26372066) and doing some more research and testing, I was able to reproduce the error with MySQLdb versions 1.2.4b4 and 1.2.5. As explained in [unubtu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12825529/2359271), this has to do with the limitations of a regular expression that appears in `cursors.py`. The exact regular expression is slightly different in each release, probably because people keep finding cases it doesn't handle and adjusting the expression instead of looking for a better approach entirely.

What the regular expression does is try to match the `VALUES ( ... )` clause of the `INSERT` statement and identify the beginning and end of the tuple expression it contains. If the match succeeds, `executemany` tries to convert the single-row insert statement template into a multiple-row insert statement so that it runs faster. I.e., instead of executing this for every row you want to insert:

```
INSERT INTO table
  (foo, bar, ...)
VALUES
  (%s, %s, ...);
```

It tries to rewrite the statement so that it only has to execute once:

```
INSERT INTO table
  (foo, bar, ...)
VALUES
  (1, 2, ...),
  (3, 4, ...),
  (5, 6, ...),
  ...;
```

The problem you're running into is that `executemany` assumes you only have parameter placeholders in the tuple immediately after `VALUES`. When you also have placeholders later on, it takes this:

```
INSERT INTO table
  (foo, bar, ...)
VALUES
  (%s, %s, ...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE baz=%s;
```

And tries to rewrite it like this:

```
INSERT INTO table
  (foo, bar, ...)
VALUES
  (1, 2, ...),
  (3, 4, ...),
  (5, 6, ...),
  ...
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE baz=%s;
```

The problem here is that MySQLdb is trying to do string formatting at the same time that it's rewriting the query. Only the `VALUES ( ... )` clause needs to be rewritten, so MySQLdb tries to put *all* your parameters into the matching group `(%s, %s, ...)`, not realizing that some parameters need to go into the `UPDATE` clause instead.

If you only send parameters for the `VALUES` clause to `executemany`, you'll avoid the `TypeError` but run into a different problem. Notice that the rewritten `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` query has numeric literals in the `VALUES` clause, but there's still a `%s` placeholder in the `UPDATE` clause. That's going to throw a syntax error when it reaches the MySQL server.

When I first tested your sample code, I was using MySQLdb 1.2.3c1 and couldn't reproduce your problem. Amusingly, the reason that particular version of the package avoids these problems is that the regular expression is broken and doesn't match the statement at all. Since it doesn't match, `executemany` doesn't attempt to rewrite the query, and instead just loops through your parameters calling `execute` repeatedly.

### What to do about it

First of all, don't go back and install 1.2.3c1 to make this work. You want to be using updated code where possible.

You could move to another package, as unubtu suggests in the linked Q&A, but that would involve some amount of adjustment and possibly changes to other code.

What I would recommend instead is to rewrite your query in a way that is more straightforward and takes advantage of the `VALUES()` function in your `UPDATE` clause. This function allows you to refer back to the values that you *would* have inserted in the absence of a duplicate key violation, by column name (examples are in [the MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)).

With that in mind, here's one way to do it:

```
dData = [[u'Daniel', u'00-50-56-C0-00-12', u'Daniel']]  # exact input you gave

sql = """
INSERT INTO app_network_white_black_list
  (biz_id, shop_id, type, mac_phone, remarks, create_time)
VALUES
  (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, NOW())
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  type=VALUES(type), remarks=VALUES(remarks), create_time=VALUES(create_time);
"""  # keep parameters in one part of the statement

# generator expression takes care of the repeated values
cur.executemany(sql, ((bsid, shop_id, dType, mac, rem) for mac, rem in dData))
```

This approach should work because there are no parameters in the `UPDATE` clause, meaning MySQLdb will be able to successfully convert the single-line insert template with parameters into a multi-line insert statement with literal values.

Some things to note:

- You don't have to supply a tuple to `executemany`; any iterable is fine.
- Multiline strings make for much more readable SQL statements in your Python code than implicitly concatenated strings; when you separate the statement from the string delimiters, it's easy to  quickly grab the statement and copy it into a client application for testing.
- If you're going to parameterize part of your query, why not parameterize all of your query? Even if only part of it is user input, it's more readable and maintainable to handle all your input values the same way.
- That said, I didn't parameterize `NOW()`. My preferred approach here would be to use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as the column default and take advantage of `DEFAULT` in the statement. Others might prefer to generate this value in the application and supply it as a parameter. If you're not worried about version compatibility, it's probably fine as-is.
- If you can't avoid having parameter placeholders in the `UPDATE` clause – e.g., because the `UPDATE` value(s) can't be hard-coded in the statement or derived from the `VALUES` tuple – you'll have to iterate over `execute` instead of using `executemany`.

Comment: Your answer is quite helpful. And I will check my source code whether there are bugs. But in another question, they figure out that this is caused by the regular express bug in MySQLdb. The following link may be more clear:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825232/python-executemany-with-on-duplicate-key-update)

Comment: @HualiangLi Thanks for the link, that's very helpful. You're right, actually, that it's related to the regex; see my updated answer for more details. (The solution is essentially the same.)

Comment: great explanation, I'v searched all day long

Comment: FWIW this solution also works for [the same bug in PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/554).

Comment: This is brilliant - very well explained.

Answer (score -1):

You have three elements in `dData` but only two `%s` placeholders for them to go into.

Comment: The 3rd line in sql has another %s.