# On duplicate key: Error - not all arguments converted during string formatting, using executemany

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am using 'insert...on duplicate key' as query for executemany, but it gives me error - "not all arguments converted during string formatting".

I have 5 columns in the table(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5).
 col1 and col5 are the keys.
In case, a duplicate entry is found, I'd update col2, col3, col4.  My query:

```
q = insert into table values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s) on duplicate key update col2 = %s, col3 = %s, col4 = %s

tuple = (val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val2, val3, val4)
#tuple above is a list. tuple = [(val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val2, val3, val4),  
                                 (val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val2, val3, val4),
                                 (val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val2, val3, val4)....]
cursor.executemany(q, tuple)
```

Upon printing the tuple, I get the following result(a list of tuples, as expected) :
 [(1029, 4, 550.0, None, 199, 4, 550.0, None)....]

**SOLUTION TO THE PROBLEM** - `q = insert into table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s) on duplicate key update col2 = values(col2), col3 = values(col3), col4 = values(col4)`
No need to pass extra parameters, update values could be taken from the values passed on to the first part of the query itself.
I got that from here - [MySQLdb returns not all arguments converted with "on duplicate key update"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337065/mysqldb-returns-not-all-arguments-converted-with-on-duplicate-key-update)

Comment: check if all tuples have 8 items. It seems that some tuple has wrong number of elements and some of elements are not used in query - they are not converted during string formatting. BTW: you can get the same error with `"%s" % (1,2)` - string has only one `%s` but tuple has two values `(1,2)`

Comment: @furas - Checked it, Sir. Every tuple has got 8 values. Could it be possible that since first part of the query requires 5 values, and I am giving 8, it is giving error? Should I somehow break the tuple( which is supplying values) into two parts, just like the query...

Comment: query has 8 `%s` so every tuple should have 8 elements. I would add code which check `len()` for every tuple to test it. Or I would try to run query with every tuple sparatelly (and print tuple before use whith query) to catch which tuple makes problem.

Comment: @furas: Finally, got the solution. Your words - "BTW: you can get the same error with "%s" % (1,2)" helped me a lot. This SOLVED my problem - `q = insert into table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s) on duplicate key update col2 = values(col2), col3 = values(col3), col4 = values(col4)`