# Upsert in mariadb/mysqldb

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mariadb

```
I have created a table as below:

    +------------------+--------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
    | Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default    | Extra          |
    +------------------+--------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
    | category         | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
    | report_id        | int(5)       | NO   | PRI | NULL       | auto_increment |
    | name             | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL       |                |
    | URL              | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
    | refresh_type     | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | On Request |                |
    | create_dt        | date         | NO   |     | 9999-01-01 |                |
    | modified_dt      | date         | NO   |     | 9999-01-01 |                |
    | project_type     | varchar(60)  | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
    | project_name     | varchar(60)  | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
    | project_location | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL       |                |
    +------------------+--------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
```

I have inserted records into this as well. I am trying to automate the process of inserting and maintaining and I am getting only few columns like category, name and URL from a data feed.

According to the process, a user can update the records and change the other fields to make them useful, and the next time when I try to insert records, I want to perform upsert based on name. I am performing the process using python. here are the steps I tried:

```
        dash= df.loc[:,['folder','name','url','url']].values.tolist()

        dash_insert_sql= ("""insert into dashboards (category 
                                                   ,name
                                                   ,URL
                                                   ) values (%s,%s,%s)
                                                   on duplicate key update URL = values(%s) """)

        cur.executemany(dash_insert_sql, dash)
```

When I try this, I am getting

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python\Mysql\report_uri.py", line 65, in <module>
        cur.executemany(dash_insert_sql, dash)
      File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 228, in executemany
        q_prefix = m.group(1) % ()
    TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Here is the example data:

My input is a list of lists.

[['Student Information', 'Active Students not Scheduled', 'https://example.com/SASReportViewer/?reportUri=/reports/reports/af4f7325-860f-4958-ad83-bb900f726b32&page=vi6', 'https://example.com/SASReportViewer/?reportUri=/reports/reports/af4f7325-860f-4958-ad83-bb900f726b32&page=vi6'], ['Student Information', 'Admissions Statistical Comparison from Snapshots', 'https://example.com/SASReportViewer/?reportUri=/reports/reports/6150909f-3ab4-4ec7-8ef0-7efdb1f09300&page=vi6', 'https://example.com/SASReportViewer/?reportUri=/reports/reports/6150909f-3ab4-4ec7-8ef0-7efdb1f09300&page=vi6']]

Please let me know how to proceed or where I am going wrong. Thank you.

Comment: I deleted my answer. I think your best bet is to search stackoverflow for similar cases. Maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825232/python-execute-many-with-on-duplicate-key-update

Answer (score 0):

dash= df.loc[:,['folder','name','url']].values.tolist()

```
    dash_insert_sql= ("""insert into dashboards (category 
                                               ,name
                                               ,URL
                                               ) values (%s,%s,%s)
                                               on duplicate key update URL = values(URL) """)
```

I tested it by changing the url of a report with that of another one and it did update the url and no new rows were added.